# TypeError: json.push is not a function while addending json objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I would like to store JSON in a textfile. Using:

```
let obj = {'column':empty,'ppas':ppa}; 
await myFunctions.addToStorage(obj);

async function addToStorage(obj) {
  const fs = require("fs");
  fs.readFile("storage.json", function (err, data) {
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    json.push(obj);
    fs.writeFile("storage.json", JSON.stringify(json), function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('The "data to append" was appended to file!');
    });
  });
}
```

storage.json contains:

```
{"column":"0:lubbock:LW2-4$","ppas":[{"ppa":50000,"url":"/"},{"ppa":51724.137931034486,"url":"/lubbock"}]}
```

when I run the program I get:

```
  json.push(obj);
         ^
  TypeError: json.push is not a function
    at /home/....functions.js:5:10
```

I can see that, the problem is that the I'm trying to stored item in storage.json is a stringified object not a stringified array of objects.

How do I set up the project so for the first object you create an array (like if storage.json does not exist)and subsequent objects are added to the array. Is there a commonly used approach to this?

Comment: Initialize the file with an empty array `[]`.

Comment: Are you expecting an array?  Because the file contains an object, not an array.  Maybe you mean `json.ppas.push`?

Comment: @Barmar - your way worked!

Answer (score 1):

**You're trying to push items onto an object, not an array**

Your code correctly converts the string to a javascript `object`, but you can't `push()` to it because objects are not arrays*, and don't have a `push()` method. Your object does *contain* an array of ppas, though.

You don't say what "array" you actually want, or what it's supposed to contain, so here's some guesses:

### Add to the array inside the json object

If you're trying to add ppa objects to the "ppa" array, you need to push to that instead: replace `json.push(obj)` with `json.ppas.push(obj)`. You don't show us where the `ppa` variable on the first line comes from, but it also needs to be an array.

### Add keys to the object

If you're trying to add another single non-ppa object to the root json object, you need to put it under a different key: change `addToStorage(obj)` to `addToStorage(key, obj)`, where key is some string, and add it with `json[key] = obj`.

---

* However, arrays *are* objects